# How to use the vue router in another file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-router, quasar-framework

The vue-router is functioning fine but we would like to push a route in another file. Some code to clarify:

```js
// src/router/index.ts
import { route } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'

export default route(function ({ Vue }) {
  Vue.use(VueRouter)
  const Router = new VueRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
    routes,
    mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
    base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE,
  })

  return Router
})
```

It would be great to be able to adjust the route in another file like this:

```js
// src/services/auth/authService.ts
import router from 'src/router'

if (router.currentRoute.path === '/login') {
  console.log('authService push to /');
  router.push('/')
}
```

But this throws the error:

> TS2339: Property 'currentRoute' does not exist on type 'RouteCallback'.

We're probably not exporting/importing the router correctly.

Comment: you need to reference it via `this.$route`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it by exporting the `Router` correctly:

```js
import { route } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'

export const Router = new VueRouter({
  scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
  routes,
  mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
  base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE,
})

export default route(function ({ Vue }) {
  Vue.use(VueRouter)
  return Router
})
```

And then consuming it outside of Vue where there is no `this` context like this:

```js
import { Router } from 'src/router'

if (Router.currentRoute.path === '/login') {
  console.log('authService push to /')
  Router.push('/')
}
```

Hope this might help others running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use route as suggested by [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties).

```
this.$route.path
```

The route will provide you with active instance of the router.

Comment: There is no `this` in the file `authService`. When I try `console.log('this', this)` it returns `undefined`.

Comment: can you post a live demo of your code in codesandbox?

Comment: Sure thing, [line 63](https://github.com/DarkLite1/hip/blob/master/src/services/auth/authService.ts).

Comment: It seems like you are accessing the route outside the vue application. Is it so?